# draw as sphere as uniform square tiles

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm experimenting with drawing spheres in WebGL, and I can't fathom how to iterate in the y-direction so that the squares appear uniform.

I believe the function is perhaps logarithmic? I've been studying WGS84 and I can't grasp the answer, but I bet someone knows exactly how Google maps is creating the sphere.

I am drawing a sphere the most simplistic method, with polar logic with the poles on the y-axis. Since I am using polar logic, the y-direction is uniform, which causes the rectangles to change shape from -90 to 0 and again from 0 to 90:

```js
function setGeometry () {
  let vertices = []

  for (let j = 0; j <= devisionCount; j++) {
    let lat = j * Math.PI / devisionCount
    let lat2 = (j + 1) * Math.PI / devisionCount
    for (let i = 0; i <= (devisionCount * 2); i++) {
      let lon = i * (Math.PI * 2) / (devisionCount * 2)
      let lon2 = (i + 1) * (Math.PI * 2) / (devisionCount * 2)
      vertices.push(radiusWide * Math.sin(lon) * Math.sin(lat)) // X
      vertices.push(radiusTall * Math.cos(lat))                 // Y
      vertices.push(radiusWide * Math.cos(lon) * Math.sin(lat)) // Z

      vertices.push(radiusWide * Math.sin(lon) * Math.sin(lat2)) // X
      vertices.push(radiusTall * Math.cos(lat2))                 // Y
      vertices.push(radiusWide * Math.cos(lon) * Math.sin(lat2)) // Z

      vertices.push(radiusWide * Math.sin(lon2) * Math.sin(lat)) // X
      vertices.push(radiusTall * Math.cos(lat))                  // Y
      vertices.push(radiusWide * Math.cos(lon2) * Math.sin(lat)) // Z
    }
  }

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
  return vertices.length
}
```

NOTE: obviously I can just do a triangle strip here, but I'm doing triangles so my fragment shader is simpler to quickly show off what I'm struggling with.

My attempts at a sphere:

[image: my-sphere]

[image: my-sphere-top]

What I am trying to replicate (Look carefully at the white lines, and notices it stays close to rectangular as we approach the poles.

[image: google-maps]

[image]